Query performance optimization in stored procedure
I am trying to optimize a query performance in Oracle that took around 40 - 50 seconds, in some cases it took 1 minute. After some analysis, I refactored code in the backend with C# and in the query, did something as follows:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetData_Rewrite 
(
  p_Id1  IN NUMBER,
  p_Id2 IN NUMBER,
  o_ResultSet OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS

 v_MyParam1 NUMBER;
 v_MyParam2 NUMBER;

BEGIN
v_MyParam1 := p_Id1;
v_MyParam2 := p_Id2;

  OPEN o_ResultSet FOR
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT
         C.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK,
         C.CONTRACT_SET_ID,
         NVL(cte.Contract_type_Desc, CT.CONTRACT_TYPE_NAME) AS CONTRACT_TYPE_NAME,
         C.CONTRACT_SET_NAME,
         C.TERM_GROUP_NAME,
         C.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
         C.CALC_START_DATE,
         CASE C.CALC_END_DATE WHEN TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'dd-mm-yyyy') THEN NULL ELSE C.CALC_END_DATE END AS CALC_END_DATE,
         C.CALC_NUM_ROWS,
         C.EDIT_STATUS_CODE AS EDIT_STATUS_CODE
      FROM
        (SELECT
          cs.CONTRACT_SET_NAME,
          cs.enterprise_id,
          MAX(cd.GROUP_NAME) AS TERM_GROUP_NAME,
          MAX(cd.UPDATE_DATE) AS LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
          MIN(cd.START_DATE) AS CALC_START_DATE,
          MAX(NVL(cd.END_DATE, TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'dd-mm-yyyy'))) AS CALC_END_DATE,
          COUNT(*) AS CALC_NUM_ROWS,
          cd.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK,
          cd.CONTRACT_SET_ID,
          MAX(
            CASE
              WHEN NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original') = 'Original' THEN 0
              WHEN NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original') = 'New' THEN 1
              WHEN NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original')  = 'Deleted' THEN 2
              WHEN INSTR(NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original'), 'Locked') = 1 THEN 3
              WHEN NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original') = 'Changed' THEN 4
              ELSE 0
            END
          ) AS EDIT_STATUS_CODE
        FROM CNTR_CONTRACTD cd
        JOIN CNTR_CONTRACT_SET cs ON (cd.CONTRACT_SET_ID = cs.CONTRACT_SET_ID AND cd.enterprise_id = cs.enterprise_id)
        LEFT JOIN CNTR_EDIT_DET ced ON (cd.CONTRACT_DETAIL_ID = ced.CONTRACT_DETAIL_ID)
        WHERE cs.COL1 = v_MyParam1
          AND cd.COL2 = v_MyParam2
        GROUP BY
          cs.CONTRACT_SET_NAME,
          cs.enterprise_id,
          UPPER(cd.GROUP_NAME),
          cd.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK,
          cd.CONTRACT_SET_ID
        ) C
      JOIN CNTR_CONTRACTD_TYPE CT ON (C.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK = CT.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK)
      LEFT JOIN CNTR_CONTRACTD_TYPE_ENT CTE ON (CTE.CONTRACTD_TYPE_ID = CT.CONTRACTD_TYPE_ID AND CTE.enterprise_id = C.enterprise_id)
    )
    ORDER BY CONTRACT_TYPE_NAME, CONTRACT_SET_NAME, TERM_GROUP_NAME;
END GetContractInfos_Rewrite;

The reason I used two extra variables to avoid parameter sniffing - Query executes in 4 seconds directly in SQL Server but takes > 30 seconds in ASP.NET?. In my case, it's a desktop app. But it still takes around 26 secs.
Is there any way to improve the query performance say to 10 - 20 secs?
In C#, I'm calling the procedure as follows:
try 
{
   using(OracleCommand cmd = (OracleCommand) mHibernateSession.Connection.CreateCommand()) 
   {
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.CommandText = "PACKAGE_NAME.GetData_Rewrite";

     cmd.Parameters.Add("p_Id1", val1);
     cmd.Parameters.Add("p_Id2", val2);

     OracleParameter paramCursor = new OracleParameter("o_ResultSet", OracleDbType.RefCursor, 2000,
       ParameterDirection.Output, true, 0, 0, string.Empty, DataRowVersion.Default, DBNull.Value);
     cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCursor);

     using(OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
     {
       adapter.ReturnProviderSpecificTypes = false;
       adapter.Fill(dtRows);
     }
   }
 } 
 finally 
 {
 }


As with all query tuning, you will need to examine the execution plan in both cases and either based on your knowledge of the data or by examining ASH and/or SQL Monitor data determine where it is going wrong. Folks can't look at a query against data they know nothing about and spot a performance problem. Any query can be okay and any query can be bad (the same is true of an execution plan considered in isolation). It's all about the data it encounters vs. the data it expects to encounter.

When I run the query in the SQL developer directly, it takes around 15 - 20 secs @Paul W.

Where are your indexes? Note,  SQL Developer may modify the query and returns only a subset of all records. Thus it looks as it would run faster. You have to fetch all rows for proper comparison.

You can't compare anything with a visual client like SQL Developer - it either fetches only the first N rows and so you see only response time to first records, or if you do configure it to fetch all, it adds a lot of time on the client for formatting/presentation visually. Either one of those is going to throw off any timing comparisons with another client. As long as it doesn't prune anything from the plan, wrapping it in select count(*) from (query) can be useful for comparing query execution (not fetch) timings in such an environment.

Also, folks when using something like SQL Developer often replace bind variables with literals for testing. If you do that, however, you frequently will get a different execution plan, so again, it is not an accurate method of comparison. The point we're making is you can't solve performance problems without examining the plan and execution information in Oracle.
